# Field values should be submitted only if the form is validated

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am submitting the form values using AJAX and in the process I want to validate the form and if any field in the form is found empty, form should not be submitted. I am not able to figure out how I should stop the form from submitting although AJAX coding is working perfectly well.

#### Don't want to use Jquery Plugin

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#sub").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "register_insert.php",
            method: "post",
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            datatype: "html",
            success: function (strMsg) {
                $("#Imsg").html(strMsg);
            }

        })

    })

    $('input').blur(function ()
    {
        if (!$(this).val())
        {
            $('#Imsg').html('Field required');
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: You are submitting your data using Ajax. That part of code will always run. Just add your test there.

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui That is what I am not able to figure out, how to add an if statement over there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't want to use an already coded jQuery plugin, you need to code function to test the validity of your form. Then, if the form is valid, you can use the AJAX code.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
      $("#sub").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if(isMyFormValid()){
          /*$.ajax({
            url: "register_insert.php",
            method: "post",
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            datatype: "html",
            success: function (strMsg) {
                $("#Imsg").html(strMsg);
            }
          })*/
          console.log('valid');
        } else {
          console.log('not valid');
          return false;
        }
      })

      function isMyFormValid(){
        var toreturn = true;
        $('input.isrequired').each(function(){
          if( !$(this).val() ){
            toreturn = false;
            $(this).addClass("red-border");
          } else {
            $(this).removeClass("red-border");
          }
        });
        return toreturn;
      }

    })
```

```css
.red-border{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input type='text' class='isrequired' name='mytext'/>
<input type='text' class='' name='mytext2'/>
<input type='text' class='isrequired' name='mytext3'/>
<button type='submit' value='submit' id='sub'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Somehow there is a problem in my form after using your code, could you plz check?

Comment: @hamaza Added the code in the question area itself. Plz see. If the fields are empty, validation msg pops up but if all the fields are filled up, date is not getting inserted.

Comment: I don't know what date you are talking about! I need to see your html form.

Comment: Actually I meant "data" but thanks anyways for your help man! I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Javascript/jQuery to do that.
You can mark a field as required with plain HTML, using `required="required"` attribute on your input fields.

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="name" required="required"/>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

See here on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gb2kw01w/2/

Comment: I am not using HTML5